# Gulp SourceMaps not working when using gulp-gzip

Tags: node.js, express, gzip, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I am using Gulp to uglify javascript files and generate their source map. So far so good:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('compress-js', ['clean-js'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./resources/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rename({extname: '.min.js'}))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
    .pipe(plugins.livereload());
});
```

This code generates the following output folders and files, which are correctly loaded by the browser:

**public/js/someScript.min.js**

```
function doSomeStuff(){console.log("This stuff function simply says: hello!!")
//# sourceMappingURL=maps/someScript.min.js.map
```

**public/js/maps/someScript.min.js.map**: Notice this file is referenced in the line above.

However I would also like to gzip them so my updated gulpfile.js is:

```
gulp.task('compress-js', ['clean-js'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./resources/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rename({extname: '.min.js'}))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(plugins.gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
    .pipe(plugins.livereload());
});
```

Now I get these files:

**public/js/someScript.min.js.gz**

```
function doSomeStuff(){console.log("This stuff function simply says: hello!!")}
//# sourceMappingURL=maps/someScript.min.js.map
```

**public/js/maps/someScript.min.js.map.gz**

The source map is not being linked because, the js.gz file references **someScript.min.js.map** instead of **someScript.min.js.map.gz**. What am I missing? How can I make the file reference the correct extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this by renaming the generated map files, removing the .gz extension:

```
gulp.task('compress-js', function(cb) {
  gulp.src('./resources/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plugins.jshint())
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rename({extname: '.min.js'}))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(plugins.gzip({ append: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
    .pipe(plugins.livereload())
    .on('end', function() {
        postProcessMapFiles('./public/js/maps/**/*.map.gz', './public/js/maps', cb);
    });
});

function postProcessMapFiles(compressedMapFiles, publicDir, cb){
    gulp.src(compressedMapFiles)
       .pipe(plugins.debug())
       .pipe(plugins.rename({extname: ''}))
       .pipe(plugins.debug())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(publicDir))
       .on('end', function() {
          del([compressedMapFiles], cb);
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did gunzip the map file.

```
var gunzip = require('gulp-gunzip');

// this task will depend on task sass, that generates the problem
gulp.task('uncompress_map', ['sass'], function () {
    var maploc = 'src/build/maps';
    return gulp.src(maploc+'/*.gz')
        .pipe(gunzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(maploc));
});
```